# check checkboxes by default which are checked on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have 2 jsp pages and on those pages I have identical multiselect checkboxes - when I click submit it goes to page2(from controller). What I am trying to do is whatever checkboxes are selected on page1 and when submit button is clicked I want those checkboxes to be checked by default on page2. I tried using local storage but it did not work. Checked checkboxes values are passed to the controller, can we do something in controller that will check check-boxes on page2. .How can I achieve desired functionality? I spent almost a day still cant implement this functionality. Appreciated for any help. Can someone please help, can’t figure out any solution for this.
[image]

```html
<div class="multiselect">
      <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
       <select multiplt="multiple">
        <option>Select an option</option>
       </select>
       <div class="overSelect"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="checkboxes">
       <label for="one"> <input type="checkbox" id="Mercedes" />Mercedes
        checkbox
       </label> <label for="two"> <input type="checkbox" id="Audi" />Audi
        checkbox
       </label> <label for="three"> <input type="checkbox" id="Volvo" />Volvo
        checkbox
       </label>
      </div>
     </div>
          
          //this is what I tried but it did not work
          //page1
         
    localStorage.setItem("Mercedes",$("#Mercedes").is(":checked"));
    
    //page2
    if (localStorage.getItem("Mercedes") == "true")
        $("#Mercedes").prop("checked","true")
```

Comment: When in page 2 lifecycle do you run this script?

Comment: My question was if you run it **after** page is fully loaded?

Comment: @Benny on onload and setup

Comment: And when in page 1 do you run **localStorage.setItem()**? And did you verify that the value in local storage is indeed ‘true’?

Comment: There is a function pageSubmit that submits form variables I am using local storage there. Yes I was testing with one value which is checked and true.

Comment: Don't know if related, but when I run the snippet here, I see the following error: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: showCheckboxes is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: verify in page 2 that the input element exists in the DOM when you change its property. Simply `console.log($("#Mercedes"))` before you change its property